# VBA to fetch html URL from webpage

Tags: html, vba, excel, macros

I have created Macro which can read all the HTML of provided URL, however I want to fetch all the url from that HTML.

```
    Sub GetHTML_Click()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim j As Integer
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True

url = Cells(1, 2)

ie.navigate url

Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to website ..."
Loop
Application.StatusBar = " "
Set html = ie.document
'Dim htmltext As Collection
Dim htmltext As String
htmltext = html.DocumentElement.innerHTML
'Need to add iURL
Dim htmlurl As IHTMLElement
For Each htmlurl In hmtltext
iurl = htmlurl.toString
Cells(j, 1).Value = CLng(iurl)
j = j + 1
Next

End Sub
```

I tried to code this to fetch the URLs however its giving "Object Required error"

can anyone please help to modify this macro which will help me to fetch all the URL from HTML page.

I am using www.mini.in website for testing.

Mayur.

Comment: you have to add to your reference the IE object. Tools->References->Microsoft Internet Controls

Comment: @winghei I have added that reference, let me check the solution provided by you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

> ```
> Dim ie As Object
> Dim html As Object
> Dim j As Integer
> Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
> ie.Visible = True
> URL = "google.com"
> ie.Navigate URL
> Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
> Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to website ..."
> Loop
> Application.StatusBar = " "
> Set html = ie.Document
> 'Dim htmltext As Collection
> Dim htmlElements As Object
> Dim htmlElement As Object
> Set htmlElements = html.getElementsByTagName("*")
> For Each htmlElement In htmlElements
>     If htmlElement.getAttribute("href") <> "" Then Debug.Print htmlElement.getAttribute("href")
> Next
> ```

Comment: this solves my issue I only updated small thing in this code so it can give me all URL on excelsheet.

Comment: `If htmlElement.getAttribute("href") <> "" Then Cells(j, 1).Value = htmlElement.getAttribute("href") j = j + 1`